# How to access templates in angularjs in a django app?

Tags: angularjs, django

I'm working on a Django app and using angular as frontend. I want to create a s.p.a. using routes. But I'm unable to access the templates, because they are in templates folder. My directory structure is like :

```
root
|-- templates
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- view1.html
|   |-- view2.html
|-- static
    |-- app.js
    |-- angular.js
    |-- angular-route.js
```

I'm a newbie in angularjs, so pls be descriptive in your answer's.
I can't change the directory structure,
Or if I'm working with render to string then how can I load the view with a api call which return me the html on page load?

Answer (score 0):

Django templates != Angular templates. Don't mix them. Angular templates are static files from Django's point of view; keep them in the static folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest separating your Angular application from your Django application if you can.

First, if you haven't done so, learn about REST API endpoints and use Django REST framework or a similar library to surface your application's data via REST API endpoints. This allows you to get your data by visiting URL's on your Django development server without it having to be served in through the Django templating engine, which is what I'm assuming you're doing at the moment. Something like:

`http://localhost:8000/api/users/`

Will return a list of users that looks something like:

```
[{
    username: 'Bob'
    email: 'bob@gmail.com'
}, {
    username: 'George',
    email: 'george@gmail.com'
}]
```

Then you can serve up your angular application as a static file through another development server using something like http-server through node.

Now your angular application can be served up through `http://localhost:8080/` and your django application can be served up through `http://localhost:8000/`. Your data for your angular application is now accessed strictly through HTTP calls, which decouples the previously intertwined and mangled frameworks.

This allows you to use angular's templating engine instead of trying to keep track of where your template files are being served through your Django server. So your folder structure for angular can look something like:

```
app
|-- index.html (includes your main angular application)
|-- templates/ (templates here)
|-- app/ (app files here)
```

This is just an example though, a good source on how to write and organize your application, which I find useful, can be found at https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide.

Let me know if you have anymore questions!